# Did animals evolve from plants?

Tags: evolution, zoology, botany

Did animals evolve from plants? Did animals' ancestors have chloroplasts in their cells?

Comment: Why do you think that animals evolved from plants?

Comment: @Michael Kuhn because animals and fungi (uniconts) evolved from biconts. Biconts currently represented only by plants.

Comment: I see! The relation of the eukaryote ancestor to the unikont/bikont split is still debated. Here's one option supported by rare genomic changes: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2817406/figure/fig4/ where a chloroplast-less ancestor acquires a chloroplast on the way to plants

Comment: Based on your comments to the answers and above... it seems that your question is "Did the common ancestor of plants and animals have chloroplasts?" In my opinion, this is quite distinct from "Did animals evolve from plants?"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See this paper "[Divergence time estimates for the early history of animal phyla and the origin of plants, animals and fungi](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1689654/pdf/10097391.pdf)" for information on the divergence estimates (I'm not sure if there are more recent papers discussing this).

Plants, animals and fungi are eukaryotes, distinct from eubacteria and archaebacteria, which are prokaryotes. The difference being in the composition of the cell, particularly a nucleus contained within a membrane for eukaryotes, along with other membrane bound organelles, e.g. chloroplasts. They all share a common ancestor, according to this paper, that split 1.576 Bya (billion years ago) +/- 88 Mya (although it states the relationships are unresolved - it is often difficult to resolve relationships so deep in a tree). They form distinct groups known as Kingdoms under Linnaean based biological classification; the Fungi, Plantae and Animalia. Thus, in answer to your question, no, animals did not evolve from plants.

Plants have chloroplasts in their cells, which provide the ability to produce energy via photosynthesis. It is thought that the chloroplast resulted from a symbiotic relationship between early plants and a cyanobacteria in that they both relied on each other for survival and so coevolved. Animals don't contain chloroplasts and instead contain an organelle called the mitochondria (although most plants also have mitochondria), which is also thought to have been a bacterial endosymbiont, probably related to [rikettsias](http://genomebiology.com/2001/2/6/reviews/1018).

Protists also contain chloroplasts. The protists are intermediate between all three groups and have been notoriously difficult to classify, being placed into a fourth Kingdom, the Protozoa, although this grouping has been contested. The current Cavalier-Smith system was proposed in 2004 and classifies life into [6 Kingdoms](http://www.cladocera.de/protozoa/cavalier-smith_2004_prs.pdf).

Chloroplasts are thought to have evolved from a single endosymbiotic event in Archaeplastida, although there are evidence to suggest some secondary endosymbiotic events. Check out [this paper](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2148/9/197) for more information; figure 1 shows the relationships between the different groups and the endosymbiotic events. The Opisthokonts are the origin of the Fungi and Animalia kingdoms.

Comment: This does not answer the question: did ancestors of animals have chloroplasts?

Comment: Ancestors of animals had mitochondria (hence the "animal equivalent of the chloroplast is the mitochondria), as did the ancestors of plants have chloroplasts. Although, it is a common misconception, that plants don't respire and in fact most plants also have mitochondria.

Comment: Edited my question to include chloroplast origin information. Hope that helps?

Comment: I wonder. Wikipedia says that Chromalveolata derivd from red algae, but your diagram shows the opposite.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, resolving the relationships of the organisms at the base of the phylogenetic tree is particularly difficult. I'm all for taking a multi-gene phylogenomic approach to this, but the more genes we add the more computationally intensive the analysis. Also, incomplete lineage sorting and other issues can compound resolution of the tree. I should imagine these things were so similar, that determining relationships is even more difficult. As we have no sequences for these organisms, we must perform ancestral state reconstruction in order to, infer the hypothetical nodes.

Comment: Here's a cool phylogenomics paper by Eugene Koonin "The origin and early evolution of eukaryotes in the light of phylogenomics" - http://genomebiology.com/2010/11/5/209

Comment: I think it's misleading to say mitochondria are the animal equivalent of chloroplasts. All plants, not just 'most', have mitochondria. Chloroplasts are only similar to mitochondria in that they are both endosymbiotic organelles. Metabolically and evolutionarily they are very different.

Comment: Also, whilst this answer has excellent phylogenetic detail, it doesn't explicitly answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @RichardSmith :) I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

No. Animals form the kingdom [Animalia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalia) (or Metazoa) which is distinct from the [Plantae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantae) kingdom.

Both evolved independently from single-celled eukaryotes.

In fact, animals are more closely related to fungi than to plants.

Comment: Did those single-celled eukariotes have chloroplasts?

Comment: @Anixx No. Chloroplasts originally developed in green algae, *after* divergence from the single-celled common ancestor of plants and metazoa.

Comment: Which implies that multi-cellularity evolved independently at least twice, once in plants and once in animals (and possibly in fungi as well). Interesting.

Comment: @Keith Ha! Actually, “[Multicellularity has evolved independently at least 46 times …](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicellular_organism#Evolutionary_history)”

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Wow. That could have some interesting implications for extraterrestrial life. Planets where life has developed but hasn't evolved beyond single-cell organisms might be less common than I would have assumed. (Unless there's something special about terrestrial single-celled organisms that makes the development of multi-cellularity unusually easy.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed, it does have these implications: There are potential hard-to-cross thresholds to higher life forms, which prevents their abundance in the Universe (and may help explain the Fermi paradox), but evolution of multicellularity is *not* one of them.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph What are these "potential hard-to-cross thresholds"? What are they called (or what should I google for)?

Comment: @user17915 Such a threshold is usually called a [“Great Filter”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Filter). There’s a good overview of the argument on [*Wait but Why*](http://waitbutwhy.com/2014/05/fermi-paradox.html).